# Android Toolbar layout is horizontal

Tags: android, layout, toolbar

I'm trying to use a couple views within a support.v7.widget.Toolbar, but it looks like they're all placed as if in a horizontal LinearLayout. I'm looking to create something more [like this](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/images/layout-structure-appbar-appbar-11_large_mdpi.png) where the EditText ends past the overflow menu, rather than where the overflow menu begins. Here's my currently layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250sp"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_id"
                    android:layout_width="40sp"
                    android:layout_height="40sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/url"
                        android:textColor="@color/accent"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/url_text_field_id"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                        android:maxLines="1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/output_text_view_id"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/initial_output_text_id"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

[Here's a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/mijjQZ9.png). You can see the views are in line with the share button and overflow menu. The title is also hidden on the left hand side by the views. **How would I have a second row for my views in the Toolbar so they span the width of the page?** Hopefully, I'm just missing something small, as I'm new to Android. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Interesting. What is the benefit of putting this in the toolbar rather than having no separator from toolbar and the next view?

Comment: I think you're right. I wanted to have them in the same container for neatness, but I ended up moving the views I had inside the `Toolbar` into a separate element in my top level linear layout. I assigned the same elevation and background colour to the toolbar and my views and now it looks as if they are all part of the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

You could, probably, put a vertical `LinearLayout` into your `Toolbar`

Comment: I changed the LinearLayout surrounding my Button and other LinearLayout to 'vertical', but it didn't solve my problem. http://i.imgur.com/xM1EoZd.png